# ListView.getChildCount() and ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() are less than real value

Tags: android, listview

I'm testing my app on a tablet in a portrait orientation. I have a ListView that has more than 50 rows in total, it displays at least 20 rows at once on the screen.

But for some reason when I use method `listView.getChildCount` it returns `9` and `listView.getLastVisiblePosition()` returns `8`. These values are too small for sure - remember, I see at least 20 rows at once. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you seeing this right from the start or after, for example, a rotation of the phone?

Comment: I see it from the start (actually, after listView was initialized)

Comment: make sure that you are calling the methods listView.getChildCount() and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() after the listview is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. ListView is loaded in `onCreate()` method and then I check childCount and lastVisiblePosition on a button click

Comment: beacause a listview only very few children, as they are recycled. 9 sounds about right

Comment: Thank you. And what about getting real value of lastVisiblePosition?